# Error while getting JSON when data has spaces

Tags: json, spring, gson

I am facing issue while fetching json data when data has white spaces .

I am using spring,
In spring controller i am doing like below,

String json=new Gson().toJson(agents, new TypeToken>() {
                    }.getType())

I am able to see proper json in logger too, after that I am setting to model attribute like below one

model.addAttribute("json",json);

here model is 'org.springframework.ui.ModelMap'

In JSP I am able fetching data till no space found.

Example :

Original JSON String: ILOVE JAVA

Fetching string in JSP: ILOVE

Only please help me out this with out using encoding string.

Comment: Your 'JSON' string is not well formed JSON. You need to quote all data strings (and all key strings). JSON syntax is very specific. You can get the full detail at [json.org](http://www.json.org)

Comment: As i said i am sending JSON String (I converted Object to string using GSON) not an JSON Object